# Как готовиться к собеседованию на позицию java middle?

Tags: java, алгоритм, spring, задание-на-собеседовании

Как бы вы посоветовали готовиться к собеседованию на позицию java middle в компанию с уклоном на генетические алгоритмы и облачные вычисления.

компания обрабатывает всякие генетические тесты для ждущих малыша вернее планирующих малыша родителей. нужно будет заниматься разработкой сервисов под облако, т.к. все вычисления идут там.

однако помимо spring cloud скорее всего будет большая нагрузка по алгоритмам.
тестовое задание это подтвердило - сделать сбалансированный граф с разными алгоритмами поиска.

тестовое задание сделал вроде все ок.
И у меня есть где-то неделя на то чтобы подтянуть.
Чтобы вы порекомендовали повторить?
Я просто последний раз собеседовался года 2 назад уже и не знаю что спрашивают.

Comment: Просто идите на собеседование с теми знаниями, которые у вас есть. Подтягивание в последний момент бесполезно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Помимо предложенного в комментариях варианта (в последний помент ничего не подтягивать), у вас есть два варианта.

Вы можете попробовать найти какой-нибудь ликбез по рабочей тематике компании. По-видимому вы знакомы с её полем деятельности, это может помочь составить определённый чеклист, который был бы вам полезен. По вашему описанию трудно что-то назвать конкретное, но я бы попробовал посмотреть в сторону различных алгоритмов оптимизации (математика, не оптимизация программного кода).

Ну и второй вариант - классика. Поработать над алгоритмической базой, возьмите любой курс по алгоритмам, и по пунктам повторите, что уже знаете, что не знаете - можно попробовать изучить, но если не пойдёт, лучше пока оставить, за неделю только сумбур в голове получится.

Список вопросов по алгоритмам легко гуглится на любой вкус. Основа, конечно - книга Кормена.

Вот один из первых примеров списка из гугла: [Шпаргалка для технического собеседования](https://habr.com/ru/company/mailru/blog/350326/).

Но это всё описание очень неточное, скажем, если предполагаемая позиция - исключительно кодер, то скорее всего алгоритмы вам особо не понадобятся, так что для более полного ответа нужно больше информации.